# konva react sdk, fade out all drawn line

Tags: konvajs, react-konva

I have a requirement to fade out all lines drawn after a fixed delay.

I followed the simple drawing example.

The code sandbox is available in the following url.

https://konvajs.org/docs/react/Free_Drawing.html

Please advise.

Comment: What did you try?